# how to use geom_segments for jitter

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter

i linked two point using geom_segments in ggplot. it works well for geom_point [image: geom_point are linked] but when i use geom_jitter it doesn't gives me the desired results [image: outcome using jitter]. I want to see the all points with line between two them. would you please help me how to connect points using geom_jitter? and why points doesn't look parallel?

I modified the code as per suggestion, now points position has been changed [image: points position has been changed]

```
ggplot() +  
geom_point(data = mydata, aes(x = lower, y = lower_p)) + 
geom_point(data = mydata, aes(x = higher, y = higher_p)) + 

geom_segment(aes(x = lower, y = ifelse(lower_p!= higher_p, NA, lower_p), xend = higher, yend = 
higher_p), data = mydata)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no example data was posted, I use some dummy data to illustrate some things. Let's set that up:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,2,2),
                 xend = c(2,2,2,3,3),
                 y = c(1,1,1,2,2),
                 yend = c(1,1,1,2,2))
```

And if we plot this similar to what you posted, we get the following plot wherein points are overplotted 2-3 times:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y), colour = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(xend, yend), colour = "dodgerblue") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend))
```

[image]

Now it might be handy to know that `geom_jitter()` is shorthand for `geom_point(position = "jitter")`. Like most positions, you can give the `position_jitter()` arguments for how you would like the jittering to occur. For example, we might want to jitter only in the y-direction:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y), colour = "red", 
             position = position_jitter(height = 0.1, width = 0)) +
  geom_point(aes(xend, yend), colour = "dodgerblue",
             position = position_jitter(height = 0.1, width = 0)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend),
               position = position_jitter(height = 0.1, width = 0))
```

[image]

As you can see, this looks horrible since every point is jittered independently from every other point. We can get closer to what we want by setting the seed for the jitter:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y), colour = "red", 
             position = position_jitter(height = 0.1, width = 0, seed = 1)) +
  geom_point(aes(xend, yend), colour = "dodgerblue",
             position = position_jitter(height = 0.1, width = 0, seed = 1)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend),
               position = position_jitter(height = 0.1, width = 0, seed = 1))
```

[image]

This now handles the left points as expected (since the seed should do the random process identically for every point), but messes up the right points. This happens because these are jittered at the same time as the left points as subsequent numbers instead of parallel to the left points.

The only reasonable solution seems to be to pre-calculate the jitter and use that such that it is the same for every point:

```
set.seed(0)
df$jit <- runif(nrow(df), -0.05, 0.05)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y + jit), colour = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(xend, yend + jit), colour = "dodgerblue") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y + jit, xend = xend, yend = yend + jit))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @teunbrand, thanks it got the lines for all points. Now when i noticed. point position has been changed. what  could be the possible reason for that? I'll try to upload new plot picture so you can see and suggest me.

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me how the point positions have changed. Could you point out how they have changed?

Comment: Hi @teunbrand, if you see the picture i have attached above, the first pair of points at bottom, there higher point was one curve, when jitter was applied then it was moved towards the left side.

Comment: I think they have only moved in the y-direction, but appear as moved in the x direction relative to your curve. If the points are too far apart, you could make  the amount of jitter smaller.

Comment: What do you mean by jitter amount smaller? Sorry I am new to this. can you recommend something to read?

Comment: From the last plot in my answer, you can adjust the +-`0.05` in `df$jit <- runif(nrow(df), -0.05, 0.05)` to change the amount of jittering. Make it a larger number and it will jitter more, make it smaller and it will jitter smaller. If you want detailed help, I propose that you include a reproducible example (data + code) in your question.

Comment: Hi @teunbrand, I got it, thanks. with smaller jitter, Position of point is same as it was before.

Comment: Hi @teunbrand, my problem was resolved, today i tried to use the same code on a different data (bigger data) so just only 4 points were connected through the line all others are even not parallel. I'll post another fresh question with modify code so if you could please look at that and suggest me where i am making mistake.